# LED pins on Arduino aren't being initialized when using classes

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I'm trying to implement classes in my traffic lights program. The issues I'm facing are that the lights do not blink and the inherited class does not seem to work. How can I fix them?

```cpp
class Sensors {
    public:
        Sensors(int echopin, int trigpin);
    Sensors();
    void init();
    double light();
    double sensor();
    // protected:
    int ECHOPIN;
    int TRIGPIN;
};

class Mode: public Sensors
//Add the VARIABLES into the CLASSES from the FUNCTIONS
{
    public: Mode(int gled, int yled, int rled, int Delay1);
    void init();
    void mode1();
    void mode2();
    void mode3();
    double sensor() {
        Sensors::sensor();
    }
    private: int Gled;
    int Yled;
    int Rled;
    int Delay;
};
Sensors sense(3, 2);
Mode mode(13, 12, 11, 2000);
void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    sense.init();
    mode.init();
}

void loop() {
    double measure;
    double lightValue;
    double MAXDISTANCE = 10;
    double MAXLIGHT = 140;

    measure = sense.sensor();
    lightValue = sense.light();
    if (measure < MAXDISTANCE) {
        mode.mode2();
    } else if (lightValue < MAXLIGHT) {
        while (lightValue < MAXLIGHT) {
            mode.mode3();
            lightValue = sense.light();
        }
    } else {
        mode.mode1();
    }
}

Sensors::Sensors(int echopin, int trigpin) {
    ECHOPIN = echopin;
    TRIGPIN = trigpin;
}
Sensors::Sensors() {
    ECHOPIN;
    TRIGPIN;
}
double Sensors::light() {
    //LIGHT SENSOR
    int sensorPin = A0;
    unsigned int value = 0;
    value = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.print("Light value is: ");
    Serial.println(value);
    return value;
}

double Sensors::sensor() {
    //Measure the distance for the RANGE FINDER
    double distance;
    double Time;

    digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(TRIGPIN, LOW);
    Time = pulseIn(ECHOPIN, HIGH);
    distance = (Time * 340) / 20000;
    Serial.print("Distance: ");
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.print(" cm \n");
    return distance;
}

void Sensors::init() {
    pinMode(ECHOPIN, INPUT);
    pinMode(TRIGPIN, OUTPUT);
}
Mode::Mode(int gled, int yled, int rled, int Delay1) {
    int Gled = gled;
    int Yled = yled;
    int Rled = rled;
    int Delay = Delay1;
}

void Mode::init() {
    pinMode(Gled, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Yled, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(Rled, OUTPUT);
}

void Mode::mode1() {
    //First Mode
    digitalWrite(Gled, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Rled, HIGH); //RED ON
    delay(Delay);
    digitalWrite(Rled, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Yled, HIGH); //YELLOW ON
    Delay -= 1000;
    delay(Delay);

    digitalWrite(Yled, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Gled, HIGH); //GREEN ON
    Delay += 1000;
    delay(Delay);
    digitalWrite(Yled, HIGH); //YELLOW ON
    digitalWrite(Gled, LOW);
    Delay -= 1000;
    delay(Delay);
}

void Mode::mode2() {
    int DELAY = 100;
    int Y_LOOP = 10;
    int buzz = 4;

    pinMode(buzz, OUTPUT);
    for (int i = 0; i < Y_LOOP; i++) {

        tone(buzz, 20);
        digitalWrite(Yled, HIGH);
        delay(DELAY);
        digitalWrite(Yled, LOW);
        delay(DELAY);
    }
    noTone(buzz);
}

void Mode::mode3() {
    double measure;

    delay(1000);
    measure = sensor();
    if (measure < 10) {
        digitalWrite(Rled, LOW);
        digitalWrite(Gled, HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(Rled, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(Gled, LOW);
    }
    delay(1000);
}
```

I expect the sensor method to return a distance, but it only does so the first time. When it is called as an inherited method it returns 0.

Comment: `double sensor() { Sensors::sensor(); }` lacks a return statement. Give `double sensor() { return Sensors::sensor(); }` a try. I'd be surprised if the compiler isn't warning you of this. If it isn't, crank up the warning level.

Comment: The output is still 0, and the lights do not turn on as well. After increasing the warning level, the compiler tells me that my variables are not being used. They are being used in the methods, so I'm not sure why that is displayed.

Comment: That is likely the error VTT brings up. If you look at your `Mode::Mode` constructor, you initialize a bunch of local variables that are never used. These local variables shadow the `Mode` member variables, replacing them inside the constructor so the member variables go uninitialized. You should also think over what `Sensors::Sensors() { ECHOPIN; TRIGPIN; }` does.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be simplified to

```
struct foo
{
    int myX;

    foo(int x)
    {
        int myX = x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f(42);
    //  f.myX is still garbage because in constuctor you initialize
    //  a local variable myX instead of object field
    return 0;
}
```

So you should initialize class field in member initializer list instead:

```
foo(int x): myX{x} 
{
     // empty
}
```